# No metadata found for property Application\Sonata\NewsBundle\Entity\Post::$tags. Please make sure your Doctrine mapping is properly configured

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata

I installed SonataNews Bundle and Extended it as ApplicationSonataNewsBundle.

When I go to `/app_dev.php/admin/sonata/news/post/list`

I have the issue message

```
No metadata found for property Application\Sonata\NewsBundle\Entity\Post::$tags. Please make sure your Doctrine mapping is properly configured.
500 Internal Server Error - MissingPropertyMetadataException
```

Someone could help me?

Environment

```
Symfony 2.8

  sonata-project/admin-bundle 3.23.0 The missing Symfony Admin
    Generator sonata-project/block-bundle 3.3.2 Symfony
    SonataBlockBundle sonata-project/cache 1.0.7 Cache library
    sonata-project/cache-bundle 2.3.1 This bundle provides caching
    services sonata-project/classification-bundle 3.3.1 Symfony
    SonataClassificationBundle sonata-project/core-bundle 3.4.0 Symfony
    SonataCoreBundle sonata-project/datagrid-bundle 2.2.1 Symfony
    SonataDatagridBundle sonata-project/doctrine-extensions 1.0.2
    Doctrine2 behavioral extensions
    sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle 3.1.6 Symfony Sonata /
    Integrate Doctrine ORM into the SonataAdminBundle
    sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle 2.2.0 Symfony
    SonataEasyExtendsBundle sonata-project/exporter 1.7.1 Lightweight
    Exporter library sonata-project/formatter-bundle 3.2.2 Symfony
    SonataFormatterBundle sonata-project/google-authenticator 1.1.0
    Library to integrate Google Authenticator into a PHP project
    sonata-project/intl-bundle 2.3.1 Symfony SonataIntlBundle
    sonata-project/media-bundle 3.6.0 Symfony SonataMediaBundle
    sonata-project/news-bundle 3.1.2 Symfony SonataNewsBundle
    sonata-project/notification-bundle 3.1.0 Symfony
    SonataNotificationBundle sonata-project/page-bundle 3.5.1 This
    bundle provides a Site and Page management through container and
    block services sonata-project/seo-bundle 2.2.0 Symfony
    SonataSeoBundle sonata-project/translation-bundle 2.1.1
    SonataTranslationBundle sonata-project/user-bundle 3.2.4 Symfony
    SonataUserBundle
```

Symfony packages

```
symfony/assetic-bundle v2.8.2 Integrates Assetic into Symfony2
symfony/monolog-bundle v3.1.0 Symfony MonologBundle
symfony/phpunit-bridge v2.8.27 Symfony PHPUnit Bridge
symfony/polyfill-apcu v1.5.0 Symfony polyfill backporting apcu_* functions to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-intl-icu v1.5.0 Symfony polyfill for intl's ICU-related data and classes
symfony/polyfill-mbstring v1.5.0 Symfony polyfill for the Mbstring extension
symfony/polyfill-php54 v1.5.0 Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 5.4+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-php55 v1.5.0 Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 5.5+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-php56 v1.5.0 Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 5.6+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-php70 v1.5.0 Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 7.0+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-util v1.5.0 Symfony utilities for portability of PHP codes
symfony/security-acl v2.8.0 Symfony Security Component - ACL (Access Control List)
symfony/swiftmailer-bundle v2.6.3 Symfony SwiftmailerBundle
symfony/symfony v2.8.27 The Symfony PHP framework
```

PHP version

```
PHP 7.0.19
```

Comment: Most likely this is a problem with invalid mapping, which has nothing to do with neither your packages nor PHP version. Update your post with code of Entity in question and remove these useless lists.

Comment: Not familiar with Symfony, but `No metadata found for property Application\Sonata\NewsBundle\Entity\Post::$tags. Please make sure your Doctrine mapping is properly configured.` suggests that you `Post` Entity is missing the `$tags` property. If that is not the case, please do what @svgrafov suggested ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, on my case this was due to class configuration. Mapping is injected during Sf DI, but my custom User Class was not found.

Just check classes used by the News Bundle.

```
sonata_news:
    class:
        post:       Application\Sonata\NewsBundle\Entity\Post
        comment:    Application\Sonata\NewsBundle\Entity\Comment
        media:      Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
        user:       My\Custom\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public function toString( $object )
    {
        return $object instanceof Subcateogry
            ? $object->getSubcateogry()
            : 'Subcateogry'; // shown in the breadcrumb on the create view
    }
```

Please Add this method in your Admin File 'Subcategory' is your file name of admin

Comment: if this where the issue, symfony would clearly state that the __toString function is missing, this seems to be mappign related,  you can use the "bin/console doctrine:schema:validate" command to verify this